# How to display more than one photo from flicker api in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, webbrowser-control, flickr

I am looking for solution how to display more than one photo in my webbrowser using winforms. I am using Flickr API to make my simple photo filtering application. I am using this method: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

With this method, I get XML file which shows 100 photos components and later from this XML I am building my Url string.
My code looks like:

```
            StringBuilder abc = new StringBuilder();
            XmlTextReader sr = new XmlTextReader(Urlstring);

            while (sr.Read())
            {
                if ((sr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && (sr.Name == "photo")))
                {
                    if (sr.HasAttributes)
                        abc.Append("https://farm" + sr.GetAttribute("farm") + ".staticflickr.com/" + sr.GetAttribute("server") + "/" + sr.GetAttribute("id") + "_" + sr.GetAttribute("secret") + ".jpg");
                    break;
                }
           }
```

With this code I get only one photo of that XML file. I want to get more, but when I remove *break;*. Webbrowser says there are no photos to display. Maybe you have any solution how to build string and read that xml that I could build more that one url and display in webbrowser application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the entire second block be srr? You are never actually reading through the srr lines, also srr contains the same lines as sr. What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @Hespen I fixed the code :)

Comment: And does it work now?

Comment: @Hespen code works to display one photo, I am looking for solution how to change that while cycle to build more url for displaying more than one photo.

Comment: If you remove the break, the browser doesn't show any pictures? If the code you provided is all that you have, that isn't really weird. You are currently appending the image url, constantly to abc. That would give you something like his: `https://example.com/image1.jpnghttps://example.com/image2.jpg` That is probably a non-existing image. You should create an arraylist to store all the URL's.